# iOS Localization: Unicode character escape sequences, which have the form '\uxxxx' does not work

Tags: ios, unicode-string, localizable.strings

We have key-value pair in Localization.string file.

```
"spanish-key" = "Espa\u00f1ol";
```

When we fetch and assign to label then app displays it as "Espau00f1ol".

**Doesn't work.**

```
self.label1.text= NSLocalizedString(@"spanish-key", nil);
```

**It works- shows in required format.**

```
self.label1.text= @"Espa\u00f1ol";
```

What could be the problem here when we use

```
NSLocalizedString(@"spanish-key", nil)?
```

**If we set \U instead of \u, then it works.**

```
 "spanish-key" = "Espa\U00f1ol";
```

**When to use "\Uxxxx" and "\uxxxx"?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`NSString` literals and strings-files use *different escaping rules*.

`NSString` literals use the same escape sequences as "normal" C-strings, in particular
the "universal character names" defined in the C99 standard:

```
\unnnn      - the character whose four-digit short identifier is nnnn
\Unnnnnnnn  - the character whose eight-digit short identifier is nnnnnnnn
```

Example:

```
NSString *string = @"Espa\u00F1ol - \U0001F600"; // Español -
```

Strings-files, on the other hand, use `\Unnnn` to denote a UTF-16 character,
and "UTF-16 surrogate pairs" for characters > U+FFFF:

```
"spanish-key" = "Espa\U00f1ol - \Ud83d\Ude00";
```

(This is the escaping used in "old style property lists", which you can see when printing
the description of an `NSDictionary.)

This (hopefully) answers your question

> When to use "\Uxxxx" and "\uxxxx"?

***But:*** As also noted by @gnasher729 in his answer, there is no need to use Unicode
escape sequences at all. You can simply insert the Unicode characters itself,
both in `NSString` literals and in strings-files:

```
NSString *string = @"Español - ";

"spanish-key" = "Español - ";
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. Still I want to know which method is recommended when it comes to localization strings file. We have to use  unicode escape sequences, because strings file is ready which contains  unicode escape sequences. Is it possible to get apple document reference where these things mentioned?

Comment: @GauravBorole: It is recommended in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html that the strings files are saved in UTF-16 encoding, which means that you can use all characters without any escape sequence, as in `"spanish-key" = "Español - ";`. But it is completely your choice, both methods work.

Comment: @MartinR Good explanation, but what is the solution when a localized string should contain an escape sequence for a unicode character, other than typing the character out?

Comment: Just copy-pasting the character even works with invisible characters; if you go to Edit > Symbols and Emoji, and type U+xxxx into the search, it will let you copy-paste that Unicode character.  (note that the character will be invisible till you click on it in the character table).  (This is needed in Swift since Objective C escape sequences are treated as a build error in Swift, if you define your localized string values in code)

Answer (score 4):

Just write the string in proper Unicode in Localization.string.

```
"spanish-key" = "Español";
```