# Swift use unicode character in localization.strings

Tags: swift, unicode, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to put a unicode character inside my localization.strings file. When I manually set a label's text to "\u{F071}", the character appears properly. When I have that character as part of a string within the localization file, then the unicode character does not appear like I want it. Is there some encoding setting that I might be missing? Or should we not have unicode characters within the localization file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452906/ios-localization-unicode-character-escape-sequences-which-have-the-form-uxxx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to follow localization.strings's unicode format, e.g.:

```
"your-key" = "\UF071";
```

Comment: Perfecto mate! Hence "\u{F071}" =  "\UF071"