# Hyphenation SwiftUI Text

Tags: swift, text, swiftui, textview, swiftui-text

How can I add hyphenation to a SwiftUI Text? Currently SwiftUI makes a paragraph when there is no space, but this makes everything hard to read and messy.

[image]

I have done a bit of research and it seems that there is no native method. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible approach is to add explicitly "soft hyphen" unicode symbols in places where you want hyphenation.

Here is a demo. Prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

Case 1: enough space

```
Text("Minded­­­\u{AD}ness")
    .frame(width: 180)        // << wide frame
    .border(Color.black)
```

[image]

Case 2: limited space

```
Text("Minded­­­\u{AD}ness")
    .frame(width: 80)        // << limited frame
    .border(Color.black)
```

[image: demo2]

*Note: Preview does not understand such unicode symbols, so test on Simulator or real device*

Comment: Not an acceptable solution imo, sorry. With UIKit you can add via attributed strings and `NSMutableParagraphStyle.hyphenationFactor `, must be something similar in swiftUI

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work with localization. Any idea how that could be achieved? EDIT: found it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630793/swift-use-unicode-character-in-localization-strings/49689269