# Localized String including emoji codes not working

Tags: ios, emoji, nslocalizedstring

My question is while

`NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Sample Text", @"Localizable", [Globals GetLocalizebundle], @"")`

is working perfect and I get Localised string from file but

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Sample Text \U0001F431", @"Localizable", [Globals GetLocalizebundle], @"")
```

can't get Localised text from bundle.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/23454538/909655 about how to include unicode characters in strings-files? Especially about code points above 0xFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by replacing whole unicode code with "surrogates".

For example  has code `"1F601"` it's surrogates are `D83D` and `DE01`. So  should be localised as `"\UD83D\UDE01"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't compile in Xcode 12.2, when put inside a `@""` literal. The complete code is needed, e.g. `\U0001F601`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use translated text for key, use something like

```
"sample_text_emoji" = "Sample Text \U0001F431";
```

in your localized.string file and then use

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"sample_text_emoji", @"Localizable", [Globals GetLocalizebundle], @"")
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle) clearly states this is a key, so use it as a key, not a text

```
 NSString *NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(NSString *key, NSString *tableName, NSBundle *bundle, NSString *comment)
```

Comment: It doesn't work really. Have you tested your solution? because it is not about the key supplied. It is about the value coming from localized.string file. I have tested `"sample_text_emoji" = "Sample Text \U0001F431"` in localized.string file, but the result on screen is "Sample Text F431"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, below solved my question but I still don't believe it is a proper solution. Anyway here the code resolves emoji characters for `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`:

```
NSString *str = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Sample Text", @"Localizable", [Globals GetLocalizebundle], @"");
NSString *stringWithEmoji = [str stringByAppendingString:@" \U0001F431"];
NSData *data = [stringWithEmoji dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *dataa = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoji = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Where base Localized.string includes `"Sample Text" = "Sample Text";`

The method is to get Localised text from bundle and then add emoji Unicode to string. Then convert it to `NSNonLossyASCIIString`. This method is working if you are using same emojis for every language.