# How to add Unicode escape sequence in Localizable.strings?

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

How can a Unicode escape sequence be added to a string in `Localizeable.strings` file if the string is casted to `NSString`?

Here is one (ugly) example:

```
// Localized string: "\u{200F}Number %@" = "\u{200E}Number %@";

let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSString(format: NSLocalizedString("Number %@", comment: "") as NSString, aNumber as NSNumber)) as String
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452906/ios-localization-unicode-character-escape-sequences-which-have-the-form-uxxx/23454538) question I understand that the problem is the incompatible escape sequences of `Localizeable.strings` and `NSString`.

Adding the unicode characters directly is `Localizeable.strings` file is not an option because I need to insert bidirectional semantics markers that are not printable characters. They would also be lost in most translation programs.

How can I work around that?

Comment: Manuel, you got the solution for this?

Comment: @iAmd If you find the question useful, then feel free to upvote it to attract more experts and maybe we get a solution for this. A workaround for me was to use the translated strings files without any copy/paste. That preserves the translator’s bi-directional semantics markers that are inserted automatically when writing RTL. If you have to change anything then make sure you change the keyboard to an RTL language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Localization: Unicode character escape sequences, which have the form '\uxxxx' does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452906/ios-localization-unicode-character-escape-sequences-which-have-the-form-uxxx)