# String with Unicode literal not displaying properly on UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, nslocalizedstring, unicode-literals

I've got some localized strings with Unicode literals in them, like so

```
"some_key" = "\u{1F6C8} Some info text";
```

which I assign to UILabel

```
myLabel.text = "some_key".localized
```

Where `localized` getter looks like that

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

I would expect the label would display [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6c8/index.htm) symbol at the beginning of my text. But instead, it just prints the symbol's code, like so

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452906/ios-localization-unicode-character-escape-sequences-which-have-the-form-uxxx

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can copy that unicode character directly to the string resource. Something like `"some_key" = " Some text";`

Edit:

But the exact unicode could return different character between iOS and android devices (happened to me). If the symbol must exactly the same across platform and it happened that the image could be added to the project asset catalog, then `AttributedText` with image attachment could be used.